# Math Proof Notation question (Not vs Complement)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, notation

I need some clarification for the following question:

Q: **Prove that :If A and B are sets in a universal set U, then $(A ∪ B)^c = A^c ∩ B^c$.**

The textbook solution started with: $$\begin{align}(A ∪ B)^c &= U − (A ∪  B) \\
&= \{x : (x ∈ U) ∧ (x ∉ A ∪ B)\} \\
&= \{x : (x ∈ U) ∧ ∼ ((x ∈ A)∨(x ∈ B))\}\end{align}$$
My question is that for "$A^c$", is this equivalent to "Not $A$" or $∼  A$. So that I can write out the above proof as the following:

$$\begin{align}(A ∪ B)^c &= \{x : x ∉ A ∪ B\} \\&= \{x : x ∈ ¬ (A ∪ B)\} \\&= \{x : (x ∈ ¬A) ∧ (x ∈ ¬B)\} \\&= \{x : (x ∈ ¬A) ∩ (x ∈ ¬B)\}
\\&= \{x : (x ∈ A^c) ∩ (x ∈ B^c)\} \\&= A^c ∩ B^c\end{align}$$

I feel like stating that $(x ∈ U)$ is a bit redundant? Like what exactly is the difference between the logic operators $∨$, $∧$ and $∪$, $∩$ ?

Thanks very much

Comment: $\vee$ is an operator in logic, and it acts on statements. $\cup$ is an operator in set theory, and it acts on sets instead. They're not interchangeable, but they mean similar things. So a statement like $A \vee B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets is meaningless, but $(x \in A) \vee (x \in B)$ makes perfect sense, and is equivalent to $x \in A \cup B$.

Comment: Thanks ! I got it now...man I feel so dumb :(. I guess my method is incorrect, since we have to state that U - (A∪B) in order to show that x ∉ A∪B. And that "A complement" is not the same as ¬A, since "A comp." = U - A while ¬A .... don't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write $x \in \neg A$

$\neg$ is a logical operator that works on statements. So, with $x \in A$ being a statement, $\neg x \in A$ would mean that it is not true that $x \in A$. But $A$ is a set, not a statement, and so $\neg A$ doesn't make sense.

You can, however, apply the complement operator on sets: $A^C$ is the set of all objects in $U$ that are not in $A$.

Indeed, the $\neg$ operator for statements and the complement operator for sets are closely related: for any set $A$, we have that $x \in A^C$ if and only if $\neg x \in A$